# logistic regression. How to get dual function?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic

Given pairs $(x_i, y_i), x_i \in R^n , y_i \in R$ we want to solve minimization
problem (logistic regression):$\min \frac{1}{2} ||w||^2 + \sum_i^{i=m}\log(1+\exp(-y w\cdot x_i))$. How to do that? I know the dual form is:
$ \min_{\alpha} D(\alpha)= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i, j}\alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j x_i \cdot x_j + \sum_i\alpha_i \log(\alpha_i) + (C-\alpha_i)\log(C-\alpha_i)$, subject to: $0\le \alpha_i\le C$. How to get dual?

Comment: What are you precisely asking about? Is this a homework?

Comment: This is really a mathematical question, but it needs improving before it can be migrated.  First, what kind of "dual" do you seek?  Second, what is $w$?  Third, why doesn't $w$ appear in your putative dual form?  Fourth, there are some typos; *e.g.*, $y$ needs to be $y_i$.  Fifth, this does not appear to be any form of logistic regression (perhaps because of the typos): what exactly is the connection?

Comment: @whuber, there are typos, but why do you say it's not a form of LR?

Comment: @Pardis I might be able to see a connection once the argument of $\exp$ is clarified.  In its current form it does not appear to be related to a log probability.

Comment: I added the explanation to my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Tom Minka gives the derivation in this excellent paper "A comparison of numerical optimizers for logistic regression" [`pdf, section 9`](https://tminka.github.io/papers/logreg/minka-logreg.pdf)

Comment: While this is good material, this is not an answer imo, more like a comment.

Comment: This is four years old. At this point, we could probably just leave it, unless the link is dead.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality 
statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?

Answer (score 2):

[LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) supports $\ell_2$-regularized logistic regression. According to the authors, the package implements the "[trust region Newton method](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/logistic.pdf)". [Here](http://videolectures.net/icml07_lin_chin_trnm/), you can find the slides to learn more, but note that it is not based on the dual formulation.

@whuber I am explaining here, because there wasn't space in the comments...

As you know, in logistic regression, the response data are chosen to be realizations of a Bernoulli random variable $Y$. In this GLM, the conditional expectation is,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \sigma\big(\mathbf{w}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x}\big)
\end{equation} 
where $\sigma(z)$ is the logistic function
\begin{equation}
\sigma(z) = \frac{1}{1+ \exp(-z)}.
\end{equation}

Here's the likelihood
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w}) = \operatorname{p}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{X};\mathbf{w}) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \operatorname{p}(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{w})\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma\big(\mathbf{w}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x}_i\big)^{y_i}\big(1-\sigma(\mathbf{w}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x}_i)\big)^{1-y_i}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and the negative log-likelihood becomes
\begin{align}
-\ell(\mathbf{w}) = -\log \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{w}) &= -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log \operatorname{p}(y_i| \mathbf{x}_i;\mathbf{w})\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\sigma\big(y_i \mathbf{w}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x}_i\big)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\big(1+ \exp\big(-y_i\mathbf{w}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{x}_i\big)\big)
\end{align}
where the last equation follows because $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

The $\ell_2$-regularization term is the result of MAP estimation of the parameters with a Gaussian prior.

Comment: I am sorry, but didn't OP ask us how to get the dual form?

Comment: that's true, I was answering the related question that came up in the comments above; additionally, I thought that the OP's main question was how to solve the $\ell_2$-regularized problem not how to obtain the dual formulation

Comment: @user1149913 seems to give a good answer to that part

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take partial derivative of minimization function with respect to unknown parameters? You can find [a lot of material](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~elkan/250B/logreg.pdf) on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lower bound of the convex function $\log(1+x)$:
$$
\log (1+x) \ge  \log(1+x_1) +(x-x_1)*(`d(\log(1+x_1))` ) 
$$
where $d(f)$ is the differentiation of $f$.

Note that the factor of $x$ on the right is your dual variable, which is in between $[0,1]$; now the problem is quadratic in $w$ and can be solved.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Ashwini. I took the liberty of using CV's $\LaTeX$ markup features to make your post more readable. Please make sure it still says what you want it to.